# Derivation of Burgers' equation in sonic boom

Tags: fluid-dynamics, shock-waves

I am studyng [Burgers equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation).
In many resources is said that this equation arise in sonic boom model.

I' m look for derivation of this equation starting from Navier-Stokes or (Euler).

I know that Burgers appear in NS if you drop the pressure term, but in sonic boom you cannot do that (the pressure is there and it is also big) ?

Can someone explain me or recommend a good resource on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the second Euler equation. For simplicity I use the 1 dimensional one, because astrophysical blast waves are often in good approximation spherical, so only the radial component matters.

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + v \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} = 0$$

From your question I assume you know how to get there. Burgers equation now follows in the isothermal regime, where we use the isothermal equation of state:

$$P=\rho a²$$

with $a$ the sound speed. Now we are in the **super**sonic regime, i.e. $a\ll v$. Therefore, we can drop the pressure term as

$$|\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}| = |\frac{a²}{\rho}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}| \ll |v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}|$$
(so, as an order of magnitude estimate the LHS is of order $a²$, whereas the RHS is of order $v²$, which is much bigger in the supersonic regime).

This leaves us with the Burgers equation:

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + v \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0.$$

Comment: Shock wave are pressure wave i expect that the burgers equation appears in the pressure term not in v? maybe i am missing some simple step? maybe if v satisfy it also p?

Comment: Mhh, I'd rather understand them as governing the flow of the fluid at hand. In the end you are interested in how the fluid *moves*, so its velocity is of interest. Often, also the "no vacuum"-condition is used, which states that at the interface the two fluids (the pre- and post-shock fluid) are in contact: $v_1=v_2=S$ with $S$ the shock-speed.